# Is there a timed signal similar to pthread_cond_timedwait?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have created many threads all waiting for there own condition. Each thread when runs signals its next condition and again goes into wait state.

However, I want that the currently running thread should signal its next condition after some specified period of time (very short period). How to achieve that?

```
void *threadA(void *t)
{
    while(i<100)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        while (state != my_id )
         {         
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_id], &mutex1);
         }
         // processing + busy wait

        /* Set state to i+1 and wake up thread i+1 */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        state = (my_id + 1) % NTHREADS;//usleep(1); 

        // (Here I don't want this sleep. I want that this thread completes it processing and signals next thread a bit later.)
        /*nanosleep(&zero, NULL);*/

        pthread_cond_signal(&cond[(my_id + 1) % NTHREADS]); // Send signal to Thread (i+1) to awake 

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Signalling a condition does *nothing* if there is nothing waiting on the condition.  So, if pthread 'x' signals condition 'cx' and then waits on it, it will wait for a very long time... unless some other thread also signals 'cx' !

I'm not really sure I understand what you mean by the pthread signalling its "next condition", but it occurs to me that there is not much difference between waiting to signal a waiting thread and the thread sleeping after it is signalled ?

Comment: My current thread (lets say 0) waits on condition0, while thread 1 waits for condition1.
Now after processing thread 0, I want to signal condition1 so that thread 1 can resume, but just before signalling, I want to schedule another process (ie I want to wait a bit). In my current code I have employed usleep. But in this scenario, after sleep gets over, the current thread will get scheduled and later it will signal next thread. I dunt want this.

Comment: Hmmm... there's a `pthread_mutex_unlock()` missing before the "`\\ processing and busy wait`.  If you don't want to delay in the current thread (eg 0) before kicking the next (thread 1), then I suggest you incorporate the delay when the thread wakes up.  If you don't want to implement the delay in either thread, then you need an auxiliary thread to be given the resposibility of kicking thread 1, and of doing that at the appropriate moment.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking. Could you help me in how to do that??

Also, the thing is I am working at a very granular level and I don't want to waste CPU cycles in doing that, so I want an external process to signal threads.. Is it possible??